# Fabricjs get RGB pixel value after zoom or pan

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I'm having trouble getting the correct mouse coordinates on the canvas after preforming pan or zoom.
I have this code for sampling coordinates and RGB:

```
        canvas1.on('mouse:move', function (e) {
            //allowing pan only if the image is zoomed.
            if (panning && e && e.e) {
                var delta = new fabric.Point(e.e.movementX, e.e.movementY);
                canvas1.relativePan(delta);
            } else {//Read the RGB value of the mouse point
                var mouse = canvas1.getPointer(e.e);

                var x = parseInt(mouse.x);
                var y = parseInt(mouse.y);

                // get the color array for the pixel under the mouse
                var px = ctx.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;

                // report that pixel data
                results.innerHTML = 'At [' + x + ' / ' + y + ']: Red/Green/Blue/Alpha = [' + px[0] + ' / ' + px[1] + ' / ' + px[2] + ' / ' + px[3] + ']';
            }
        });
```

problem is that after zoom/pan the coordinates are 'wrong',
for example the top left corner in not (0, 0) but (-someX, -someY)...

any help will be appreciated

EDIT: I've found the mistake, 
this will fix it. hope it will be useful for someone else

```
                var x = e.e.offsetX;//parseInt(mouse.x);
                var y = e.e.offsetY;//parseInt(mouse.y);
```

Comment: Do me a favour? Put your answer below and mark it "accepted".  Therefore, consistent with how Stack Overflow is design...  helping others see quickly that the question is addressed.  Thanks and please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code solves it,
Hope it could be useful for others.

```
 canvas1.on('mouse:move', function (e) {
        //allowing pan only if the image is zoomed.
        if (panning && e && e.e) {
            var delta = new fabric.Point(e.e.movementX, e.e.movementY);
            canvas1.relativePan(delta);
        } else {//Read the RGB value of the mouse point
            var mouse = canvas1.getPointer(e.e);

            var x = e.e.offsetX;//parseInt(mouse.x);
            var y = e.e.offsetY;//parseInt(mouse.y);

            // get the color array for the pixel under the mouse
            var px = ctx.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;

            // report that pixel data
            results.innerHTML = 'At [' + x + ' / ' + y + ']: Red/Green/Blue/Alpha = [' + px[0] + ' / ' + px[1] + ' / ' + px[2] + ' / ' + px[3] + ']';
        }
    });
```